# String comparision in GNUMakefile is always true

Tags: string, makefile, gnu-make

I have a logical condition in GNUMakefile in which I compare the strings. It is always falling into the if branch irrespective of the value of the variable which I am comparing.

```
myRecipe:
    $(eval PLAT := /tmp) \
    if [ $(SYS_NAME) = linux-x86 ]; then \
        $(eval PLAT := /temp) \
        echo $(PLAT); \
    fi
```

If $(SYS_NAME) is linux-x86 it extecutes as:

```
\
        if [ linux-x86 = linux-x86 ]; then \
             \
            echo /temp; \
    fi        
/temp
```

If $(SYS_NAME) is aix61, it executes as:

```
\
    if [ aix61 = linux-x86 ]; then \
             \
            echo /temp; \
    fi
```

Why is the string comparison not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix shell conditionals:

```
if [ $(SYS_NAME) = linux-x86 ]; then
```

with GNU make functions:

```
$(eval PLAT := /temp)
```

The GNU make functions will unconditionally be executed.

You should use GNU make conditionals `ifeq` etc instead (possibly using `$(shell)`).

Also, make sure you don't confuse make variables `${FOO}` with shell variables `$${FOO}`

Answer (score 0):

When *make* decides to execute your recipe, it expands the entire recipe in one go, and then executes each line in the result, one by one, each in a separate shell.

Thus in your example, *make* expands

```
$(eval PLAT := /tmp) \
if [ $(SYS_NAME) = linux-x86 ]; then \
    $(eval PLAT := /temp) \
    echo $(PLAT); \
fi
```

In painful detail:

- `$(eval PLAT := /tmp)` becomes the empty string. As a side effect of the expansion, the `PLAT` *make* variable becomes `/tmp`.
- `$(SYS_NAME)` becomes `linux` (say)
- `$(eval PLAT := /tmp)` is empty, with `PLAT` becoming `/temp`

*Make* is left with

```
if [ linux = linux-x86 ]; then \
    echo /temp; \
fi
```

which it dutifully passes to a single shell (since it is a single line).